# How to control UI changes on orientation change?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing a fairly simple app that works just fine in portrait (and fine in landscape, in that it doesn't die), but I'd like to shift the UI around a little to make better use of the landscape orientation.

I know how to create a landscape layout - layout-land and so forth - but I'd quite like to add a couple of UI elements to the landscape layout that don't exist in portrait's.

Obviously, if I try to run code on these elements in portrait mode, Android will scream about not being able to find them.

So, is the correct thing to do here just to enclose all of that work inside `if (weAreInLandscape){}` code, or is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: You just check if `findViewById` returns null, and have the code do something sensible.  This is done all the time with layouts for alternate configurations.  Of course, if your object keeps a reference to the widget, you have to check for null anytime you go to do something with that reference.

Answer (score 0):

> So, is the correct thing to do here just to enclose all of that work inside if (weAreInLandscape){} code, or is there a better way?

Yes, it's really good way but first you need to do separate code for both views from code for one special view, here landscape. For this moment comment the code for landscape. Then try to catch orientation of change. It could be done by this line of code:

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

Read: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#orientation

If you now know how to get orientation screen add `Boolean` value which would keep value of `isLandscapeMode`.

Why `boolean`. It's easy to immplement and in case you would add to all of your class existing methods some extra code depended on orientation screen - i think it would much easier to do, than putting all in one method.

So, to resume, your solution is good and hope you do implement it.